# Angular @input value when route change

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 8 and I have a two components: father and child.

The father component has to send an object or a string when the url parameters change.

In the father component I have written this code, that is able to understand if the url has changed and to set the `urlParam` for the child:

```
  this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      this.urlParam = JSON.stringify(paramMap);
   
  });
```

father html:

```
<search [searchCriteriaForm]="searchCriteriaForm" [urlParam]="urlParam"></search>
```

In the child component, I have put this:

```
 @Input() set urlParam(urlParam: string) {
  console.log('The child has well received');
 }
```

When the url change I see that the data arrives to the father component but not to the child.

I have noted that when I load the page (the first time) the child receives very well the parameters but when I change the url (without to reload or refresh the browser page) only the father is able to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest going reactive in this scenario since it's a bit difficult to pinpoint the issue.

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

// define this on field level
urlParam = new BehaviorSubject("");
//...

  this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      this.urlParam.next(JSON.stringify(paramMap));
  });
```

html

```
<search [searchCriteriaForm]="searchCriteriaForm" [urlParam]="urlParam | async"></search>
```